# Making a menu with collapse and expand... not working

Tags: html, css, menu

Maybe you guys can help me out. I'm trying to make a menu for a MVC project i'm doing. I want the functionality that you get from using bootstrap, when minimizing it turns into a hamburger menu.

But everytime i try it it fails, i try adding the bootstrap code necessary. But the first of all doesn't work properly, secondly removes all my css.

Maybe i shouldn't use bootstrap at all. What i want is the menu to collapse when i make the window smaller and expand when i make it bigger to the size i have set.

I have set properties on the menu. So all i want now is for the menu to become smaller and then return to main size.

Can you guys help me out?

```
    <header>
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="arrows">
                    <span class="ar-left"></span>
                    <span class="ar-right"></span>
                    <span class="ar-left2"></span>
                    <span class="ar-right2"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="dark-color">
                    <div class="light-color">
                        <a href="#" id="logo" style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'">Test</a>
                        <nav>
                            <ul style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'">
                                <li><a href="../Home/Index" class="active-menu">Hem</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../One/Start">One</a></li>
                                <li><a href="../Two/Start">Two</a></li>
                                <li><a href="~/Three/Login">Log in</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</header>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)! You need to try to write the code **yourself**. After doing [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and you still have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of **what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: where's your css?

Comment: Hello Sankarsh! Honestly i've only been struggling with this since 10 this morning. So it's 11 hours only now (8 of them coding). But i have tried taking code from different websites, most of them with the same solution using bootstrap. But everytime i do that it deletes my css.

Comment: Michael - It's in the css file. Sorry i didn't add it. Can send it to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexbox to display the menu in a row when the screen is bigger. Once it hits the breakpoint, display the hamb icon. I implemented one in this example using some JQuery to make it work once its clicked. When clicked the class active is added to the main-menu class set on the ul changing the style to flex-direction: column.

```js
$(".hamb").click(function(){
  $(".main-menu").toggleClass("active");
  $(".spanf ").toggleClass("span1 ");
  $(".spans ").toggleClass("span2 ");
  $(".spant ").toggleClass("span3 ");
});
```

```css
nav{display: flex; background-color: #000000;}
.hamb {
  background: #000000;
  width: 75px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
}

.hamb span i {
  width: 45px;
  height: 10px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}

.span1 .span2 .span3 i {
  position: absolute;
}

.hamb .spanf:nth-child(1) i {
  top: 20%;
}

.hamb .spans:nth-child(2) i {
  top: 40%;
}

.hamb .spant:nth-child(3) i {
  top: 60%;
}

.span1:nth-child(1) i {
  top: 40% !important;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.span2:nth-child(2) i {
  left: 130px;
}

.span3:nth-child(3) i {
  top: 40% !important;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.main-menu{
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style:none;
  display: flex;
  width: 25%; 
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #000000;
  animation: fadeIn 0.5s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
@keyframes fadeIn{
  0%{opacity: 0;}
  100%{opacity:1;}
}

.main-menu li {text-align: center; padding: 5px 0;}

.main-menu li a{color:white; text-decoration: none;}


@media (max-width: 768px){
  .hamb{
    display:block;
  }
  .main-menu{display:none;}
  .active {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.main-menu li{border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
.main-menu li:nth-last-child(1){border-bottom: none;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
  <div class="arrows">
      <span class="ar-left"></span>
      <span class="ar-right"></span>
      <span class="ar-left2"></span>
      <span class="ar-right2"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="dark-color">
      <div class="light-color">
          <a href="#" id="logo" style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'">Test</a>
          <nav>
<div class="hamb"><span class="spanf"><i></i></span><span class="spans"><i></i></span><span class="spant"><i></i></span></div>
            
              <ul style="font-family: 'Segoe Print'" class="main-menu">
                  <li><a href="../Home/Index" class="active-menu">Hem</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../One/Start">One</a></li>
                  <li><a href="../Two/Start">Two</a></li>
                  <li><a href="~/Three/Login">Log in</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">five</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Julian. I edited your example a bit. And it's almost working now. Thank you for your help. I just have a few more things to solve, the menu is really big right now when collapsed. But i will manage. Thank you for your help. I should have thought of javascript though.